# Podman config weird behavior

Tags: podman

I'm trying to use Podman in rootless mode and getting "Error: chmod /media/user: operation not permitted". I've set the graphroot and rootless_storage_path in /home/user/.config/containers/storage.conf (see below). Here's the weird thing.. when I change the runRoot in this file and check `podman info` nothing happens. But when I then change the graphRoot and check, the runRoot is changed. Even weirder, when I change the graphRoot back, it changes the runRoot back by itself.

Anyone can explain this? Thx

```
[storage]

# Default Storage Driver, Must be set for proper operation.
#driver = "overlay"
driver = "vfs"

# Temporary storage location
#runroot = "/media/user/temp/containers/run"
runroot = "/run/user/1000"

# Primary Read/Write location of container storage
graphroot = "/media/user/temp/containers/storage1"

# Storage path for rootless users
rootless_storage_path = "/media/user/temp/containers/storage"
```

I created an issue on the GitHub: https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/18692